# Sharing razor views across projects using a shared library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to share a razor view from one project to another. At first, I've tried to use RazorGenerator extension ([Precompile your MVC Razor views using RazorGenerator](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html))

However, I am only using VS 2013 Web Express so I couldn't use the extension properly (I can only use Web Express).

Now, I've tried this: [Sharing MVC Views](https://www.leapinggorilla.com/Blog/Read/1024/sharing-mvc-views), but I can't make it find the view. What I did was I created a class library "ClassLibrary2", added a folder "Views" and under it "Shared". In the "Shared" folder, I added a view "MyView.cshtml" (this file is empty) and then compile the project with "MyView.cshtml" setted as an embedded resource.

After this, I created a new MVC project (the MVC template), referenced "ClassLibrary2" and added the code mentioned in the page (the "EmbeddedResourceViewPathProvider" and the "EmbeddedResourceFile" classes). Also added the code on Application_Start() and in the code for "EmbeddedResourceFile", I've changed to:

```
var resourcename = 
        virtualPath
        .Substring(virtualPath.IndexOf("Views/"))
        // NB: Your assembly name here
        .Replace("Views/", "ClassLibrary2.")
        .Replace("/", ".");
```

But still, cannot find the view.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while trying to do something similar myself, and I was able to use the linked article (Sharing MVC Views) to accomplish sharing a view as a resource from another assembly. If you're still trying to solve this problem, posting a little more of your code might help. I found that the method didn't quite work for me out of the box; the fundamental problem was that it's a little tricky to ensure that the resource name request "hits" your EmbeddedResourceViewPathProvider.

Specifically, the GetResourceName function on the EmbeddedResourceFile class will take a virtual path (like "~/Views/_foo.cshtml") and try to convert it to the name of a resource (like MyApplication.SomeNamespace._foo.cshtml); this line:

```
   var resourcename = 
        virtualPath
        .Substring(virtualPath.IndexOf("Views/"))
        // NB: Your assembly name here
        .Replace("Views/", "LeapingGorilla.Common.MVC.Views.")
        .Replace("/", ".");
```

Is perhaps misleading because it says "Your assembly name here", when really what you want there is a namespace (not necessarily the same, and indeed not the same in my case). I found it helpful to implement the suggested solution, then debug through the ResourceFileExists function to see what the solution was looking for. Let's take an example:

Let's say I have a project named ViewLibrary with a folder/file structure like this:

```
ViewLibrary
|-->Web
|---->Views
|------>_example.cshtml
```

And in a web project which references ViewLibrary, I have a Razor file that asks for ~/Views/_example.cshtml. MVC will attempt to find the resource in all of its VirtualPathProviders, so eventually the GetResourceName function will be called looking to resolve ~/Views/_example.cshtml into a resource name. In our example. the resource is named ViewLibrary.Web.Views._example.cshtml, so the replacement would need to look like:

```
.Replace("Views/", "ViewLibrary.Web.Views.")
```

Another problem I had is that MVC will lower-case the path names, so you may have to adjust your function that actually gets the resource so account for this. For my solution, I actually had my path provider pass the resource file object the array of resource names to resolve it in a case-insensitive way. Here's an entire example of how I accomplished this to put it all together:

ViewLibrary/EmbeddedResourceViewPathProvider.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace ViewLibrary
{
    public class EmbeddedResourceViewPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
    {
        private readonly Lazy<string[]> _resourceNames =
            new Lazy<string[]>(() => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames(),
                LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

        private bool ResourceFileExists(string virtualPath)
        {
            var resourcename = EmbeddedResourceFile
                                .GetResourceName(virtualPath);
            var result = resourcename != null
                && _resourceNames.Value.Select(v => v.ToLower()).Contains(resourcename.ToLower());

            return result;
        }

        public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
        {
            return base.FileExists(virtualPath)
                || ResourceFileExists(virtualPath);
        }

        public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
        {
            if (!base.FileExists(virtualPath))
            {
                return new EmbeddedResourceFile(virtualPath, _resourceNames);
            }

            return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewLibrary/EmbeddedResourceFile.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace ViewLibrary
{
    public class EmbeddedResourceFile : VirtualFile
    {
        private readonly Lazy<string[]> resourceNames;

        public EmbeddedResourceFile(string virtualPath) :
            base(virtualPath)
        {
            resourceNames = null;
        }

        public EmbeddedResourceFile(string virtualPath, Lazy<string[]> resourceNames) :
            base(virtualPath)
        {
            this.resourceNames = resourceNames;
        }

        public static string GetResourceName(string virtualPath)
        {
            if (!virtualPath.Contains("/Views/"))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var resourceName =
                virtualPath
                .Substring(virtualPath.IndexOf("Views/"))
                .Replace("Views/", "ViewLibrary.Web.Views.")
                .Replace("/", ".");

            return resourceName;
        }

        public override Stream Open()
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var resourceName = GetResourceName(VirtualPath);
            // Make resource search case-insensitive
            if (resourceNames != null)
            {
                string foundResource = resourceNames.Value.FirstOrDefault(v => v.ToLower() == resourceName.ToLower());
                if (foundResource != null)
                {
                    resourceName = foundResource;
                }
            }
            return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps, and thanks for pointing me to that article which helped me solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty good write-up from Mira Javora using Visual Studio Extension RazorGenerator...

http://blog.mirajavora.com/re-use-mvc-views-across-projects-with-razor-generator/

Effectively, this write-up uses the RazorGenerator tool to compile the .cshtml file into .cs files.  The resulting .cs file includes a virtual path - such as...

```
[System.Web.WebPages.PageVirtualPathAttribute("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml")]
```

I followed the instructions on the write-up and it worked pretty much first time.  Good article.